# Mocha/Chai check if keys exist on an objects prototype

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I am writing tests using Mocha/Chai and `assert.hasAllKeys` works for keys not on an objects prototype. Is there a way to check if keys exist on an objects prototype?

I've tried reading the docs to no avail.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use this way

```
assert.hasAllKeys(YourObject.prototype, ['prop1', 'prop2']);
```

Here is the code example:

**src.js**

```
function MyObject () {

}

MyObject.prototype.prop1 = function() {
  console.log('ok');
}

MyObject.prototype.prop2 = 10;

module.exports = {
  MyObject
};
```

**test.js**

```
const chai = require('chai');
const src = require('./src');
const assert = chai.assert;

describe('unit test', function() {
  it('runs test', function() {    
    assert.hasAllKeys(src.MyObject.prototype, ['prop1', 'prop2']); // check object prototype       
  })
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
/**
*  @returns bool true if propName exists in proto only
*/
const propInProtoOnly = (propName, objToCheck) =>
propName in objectToCheck && !objectToCheck.hasOwnProperty(propName)
```

is good enough? )